# NoClassDefFoundError from EmailConverter.outlookMsgToMimeMessage

Tags: email

I wrote below code to test mail conversion from bababab.msg to MimeMessage object. The sample message is taken from outlook2010. Im getting "NoClassDefFoundError" when trying to execute the conversion method.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.simplejavamail.converter.EmailConverter;

public class TestMail {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileInputStream fis;
    try {

        File msg = new File("C:\\Users\\bababa\\Desktop\\samplemail\\bababab.msg");

        if (msg.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File exist");
        }

        fis = new FileInputStream(msg);
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = EmailConverter.outlookMsgToMimeMessage(fis);

        if (null != mimeMessage) {
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Error log:

```
File exist
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/DirectoryEntry
at org.simplejavamail.converter.internal.msgparser.OutlookMessageParser.parseOutlookMsg(OutlookMessageParser.java:35)
 at org.simplejavamail.converter.EmailConverter.outlookMsgToEmailBuilder(EmailConverter.java:100)
at org.simplejavamail.converter.EmailConverter.outlookMsgToEmail(EmailConverter.java:92)
at org.simplejavamail.converter.EmailConverter.outlookMsgToMimeMessage(EmailConverter.java:142)
at TestMail.main(TestMail.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryEntry
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 5 more
```

Comment: @Benny Bottema Hope you could help.